# Adding properties to an entity without using poco classes

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have an instance of an EF entity that im serializing to JSON. Is there any way to add some properties to it, without using a POCO class? Maybe create a new object and attach it, if thats possible?

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(serializer.Serialize(system.OrderByDescending(s => s.SYSTEM_ID)));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(
    serializer.Serialize(
        system.OrderByDescending(s => s.SYSTEM_ID).Select(s => new {
            s.SYSTEM_ID,
            NewProperty = "Foo"
})));
```

I don't know where your code gets executed, but using `HttpContext` `Response.Write` directly is a bit of a smell.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its a generic handler which is generating json

Comment: Hmm, i noticed that the original properties are removed. Is there any workaround?

Comment: @Johan: Use `MyEntity = s,` instead of `s.SYSTEM_ID` in the `Select(s => new {...`. `MyEntity` will contain then ALL properties of your entity.

Answer (score 0):

The classes EF generates are partial...

You can add an additional file which adds properties and methods to them.

E.g.

```
public partial class MyEntity
// no need to specify base or interfaces as they are specified elsewhere
{
    // Add stuff here
}
```

Comment: @JakubKonecki My answer does **not** assume that POCO classes are used.